# Can you explain the tense structure here in this dialogue?

Tags: tense, tense-agreement

> If you lay even a hand on him, you are dead.

That was telecasted in a naruto episode.I wondered it should be **you would be dead.**
Can you explain me this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you lay even a hand on him, you are dead.

This is correct. *Lay* is present *realis* with contingent future reference, and so is *are*. The statement is equivalent to

> If you touch him you are dead.

You may be confused by *lay*, which has the same spelling as the past-tense form of *lie*. But *lie* is intransitive and cannot take an object like *a hand*; this *lay* has to be the present-tense form of *lay*.

Comment: If you touch him you would be dead.Shouldn't this be?

Comment: @AnubhavSingh No. In a conditional the condition and consequence clauses must have the same 'reality'. We say if *If you **touched** him you would be dead* but *If you touch him you **are*** or ***will be** dead.*

Comment: **You will be dead** is alright but **are dead** is something which had happened already.You touched him, so you are dead.You are dead because you touched him.

Comment: @AnubhavSingh No. 1) *are dead* is not something which has happened already--it doesn't 'happen' at all, it is a state. 2) It is a state which *will be* the case if you touch him--*are* is a present-tense for with future reference. This might also be expressed as an event: *If you touch him you **die***.